# Как задать строгий порядок элементов при конвертации обеъекта имеющего переменную списка объектов в XML при помощи XMLMapper?

Tags: java, xml, list, jackson

У меня следующая проблема:
есть два класса:

```
public class Order {

   @JsonProperty("customer_id")
   private UUID customerId;

   @JsonProperty("id")
   private UUID id;

   @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "products")
   private List<Item> items;

}


public class Item {

   @JsonProperty("id")
   private UUID productId;

   @JsonProperty("quantity")
   private Integer quantity;
}
```

Я пытаюсь их экспортировать в XML и обратно:

```
public class OrderXmlConverter {

   public static String convertToXml(Order order) throws IOException {
       /*изначально был такой метод, немного его дополнил по советам из гайда
       на baeldung, но не помогло:
       XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
       return xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(order);*/

       XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
       ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       xmlMapper.writeValue(byteArrayOutputStream, order);
       return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();


   } 

   public static Order convertFromXml(String xml) throws JsonProcessingException {
       XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
       xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
       return xmlMapper.readValue(xml, Order.class);
   }
  }
```

В принципе, у меня это получилось при помощи Jackson, но элементы в рамках блока products всегда сохраняются в разном порядке. А именно:
Первый запуск:

```
<Order>
<products>
    <items>
        <id>2d1518c0-cc3d-4046-926b-0e17a26dedb7</id>
        <itemIdAndQuantitysAsString>id: 2d1518c0-cc3d-4046-926b-0e17a26dedb7 quantity: 1,</itemIdAndQuantitysAsString>
        <quantityOfItem>1</quantityOfItem>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
    </items>
</products>
<productsAndQuantityAsString>id: 2d1518c0-cc3d-4046-926b-0e17a26dedb7 quantity: 1,</productsAndQuantityAsString>
<products>
    <products>
        <id>2d1518c0-cc3d-4046-926b-0e17a26dedb7</id>
        <itemIdAndQuantitysAsString>id: 2d1518c0-cc3d-4046-926b-0e17a26dedb7 quantity: 1,</itemIdAndQuantitysAsString>
        <quantityOfItem>1</quantityOfItem>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
    </products>
</products>
<customer_id>de8ce59a-f226-457d-8f08-1be7b0097a03</customer_id>
<id>c088babc-fea4-48d9-8346-c381fdeff555</id>
</Order>
```

Второй запуск:

```
<Order>
<products>
    <items>
        <id>394db20c-693b-407a-9fe8-9c7cc18d6797</id>
        <quantityOfItem>1</quantityOfItem>
        <itemIdAndQuantitysAsString>id: 394db20c-693b-407a-9fe8-9c7cc18d6797 quantity: 1,</itemIdAndQuantitysAsString>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
    </items>
</products>
<productsAndQuantityAsString>id: 394db20c-693b-407a-9fe8-9c7cc18d6797 quantity: 1,</productsAndQuantityAsString>
<products>
    <products>
        <id>394db20c-693b-407a-9fe8-9c7cc18d6797</id>
        <quantityOfItem>1</quantityOfItem>
        <itemIdAndQuantitysAsString>id: 394db20c-693b-407a-9fe8-9c7cc18d6797 quantity: 1,</itemIdAndQuantitysAsString>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
    </products>
</products>
<customer_id>91c0cc94-21cb-4ac9-94bd-8c380b93d1be</customer_id>
<id>8401d4c0-bbac-4006-9760-75e9b6d7d628</id>
</Order>
```

В теории, мне это не мешает, визуально я убедился, что данные экспортируются-импортируются корректно. Но в тестах я планировал вручную сгенерировать ожидаемую строку и сравнить её, а вот с этим начинаются проблемы: т.к. порядок элементов меняется, то часто валидная XML-строка отмечается как неправильная.

Вопрос: как я могу задать строгий порядок элементов для XML объекта?
И мини-вопрос: почему у меня products дублируются, но в одном случае элементы зовутся items, по названию переменной, а в другом - products, по локальному имени враппера? Я ожидал что будет только второй блок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать аннотацию `@JacksonXmlProperty` вместо `@JsonProperty`.

аннотация должна быть над каждым полем, тогда порядок будет сохраняться, и название элементов внутри `wrapper` будет всегда `products`, если опишите так:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "products")
private List<Item> items;
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, то что я искал!